# A question on Banach space involving an invariant mean on $\mathbb Z$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis, isometry

Let $E$ be a Banach space and suppose $T\in Aut(E)$ satisfies the condition $\|T^n\|\leq C$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$ for some fixed $C\in \mathbb R$. I have to show that there is an equivalent norm on $E$, say $|\ |$, such that $T$ is isometric with respect to $|\ |$.

As a hint, it is given that, for $x\in E $, define $f(n)=\|T^n(x)\|$. Then $f\in l^{\infty}(\mathbb Z)$ and then it is advised to use invariant mean on $\mathbb Z$.

I am not sure about how to proceed from there. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

If you want to recall the definition of invariant mean, you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272989/existence-of-invariant-mean-for-mathbbrn)

Comment: So the condition $\|T^n\|\le C$ means that there exists some $C\ge0$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ $\|T^n\|\le C$? or just for some $n$?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn: I’d say the former, because $T=2I$ is otherwise a counterexample.

Comment: @Mindlack Yeah, it makes more sense for it to be the former anyway.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn for all $n$, $\|T^n\|\leq C$. Sorry, I will make the necessary edit.

Comment: Can’t you just take $|x|=\sup_n \|T^nx\|$?

Comment: I am wondering though, why not just take as $\|\cdot\|'$ the norm defined by $\|x\|'=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\|T^nx\|$? This is obviously a norm, satisfies $\|x\|\le\|x\|'\le C\|x\|$ and $\|Tx\|'=sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\|T^{n+1}x\|=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\|T^nx\|=\|x\|'$

Comment: @JustDroppedIn yeah, then what's the point of that hint? Is that unnecessary? Are we missing something?

Comment: It's your question so you think about it. As you posted it here, this norm works perfectly fine for the problem.

Comment: Any thought about my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known that $\mathbb Z$(and all abelian semigroups) are amenable. Let $\mu$ be an invariant mean on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb Z)$. $|x|=\mu(f)$ defines a norm on $E$ (why?). This norm is equivalent to $\|.\|$. In fact
$$|x|=\mu(f)\leq \|\mu\|\|f\|\leq C\|x\|.$$
Note that $\|\mu\|=1$ by definition of a mean. At the other hand, for each $n\in \mathbb Z$,
$$\|x\|=\|T^{-n}T^nx\|\leq C\|T^nx\|.$$
By positivity of means, we have
$$\|x\|\leq C\mu(\|T^nx\|)=C\mu(f)=C|x|.$$

Also $T$ is isometric with respect to $|.|$, since
$$|Tx|=\mu(\|T^{n+1}x\|)=\mu(\|T^nx\|)=|x|.$$
Note that for each invariant mean $\mu$, $\mu_n(f(n))=\mu_n(f(n+1))$.